# Score not changing in python pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a pong game, but the score is not changing when the ball goes off the screen. Another thing that isn't quite right is that sometimes, the ball slides on the paddle and then go off of the screen, instead of bouncing off of the paddle. Can I get some help on these problems? (mainly the first one) Here's my code:

```
import pygame as pg
import random
from os import path

img_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'img')
snd_dir = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'snd')
WIDTH = 1280
HEIGHT = 690
FPS = 60
# define colors 
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (0, 255, 255)
OPPONENT_SPEED = 2.4
# initialize PyGame and create window 
pg.init()
pg.mixer.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pg.display.set_caption('PONG!')
clock = pg.time.Clock()
pong_ball_x = [-3, 3]
pong_ball_y = [-3, 3]
font_name = pg.font.match_font('arial')


def draw_text(surf, text, size, x, y):
    font = pg.font.Font(font_name, size)
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, WHITE)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect()
    text_rect.midtop = (x, y)
    surf.blit(text_surface, text_rect)


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 100))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 10
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedy = 0
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_s]:
            self.speedy = 5
        if keys[pg.K_w]:
            self.speedy = -5
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0


class Player2(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 100))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = WIDTH - 15
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speedy = 0
        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pg.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 5
        if keys[pg.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = -5
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0


class Opponent(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 100))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = WIDTH - 10
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.rect.top = 0

    def opponent_ai(self):
        if self.rect.top < pong_ball.rect.y:
            self.rect.top += OPPONENT_SPEED
        if self.rect.bottom > pong_ball.rect.y:
            self.rect.bottom -= OPPONENT_SPEED


class PongBall(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = WIDTH / 2 - 12.5
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2 - 12.5
        self.speedx = random.choice(pong_ball_x)
        self.speedy = random.choice(pong_ball_y)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.speedy = -self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.speedy = -self.speedy
        if self.rect.right <= 0:
            self.rect.x = WIDTH / 2 - 15
            self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2 - 15
        if self.rect.left >= WIDTH:
            self.rect.x = WIDTH / 2 - 15
            self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2 - 15

    def bounce(self):
        self.speedx = -self.speedx
    # load all game graphics 


# ball_img = pg.image.load(path.join(img_dir, "white_circle2.png")).convert() 
all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
pong_ball_group = pg.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
player2 = Player2()
opponent = Opponent()
pong_ball = PongBall()
all_sprites.add(player)
all_sprites.add(player2)
pong_ball_group.add(pong_ball)
score = 0
score2 = 0
# Game loop 
running = True
while running:
    # process input (events) 
    for event in pg.event.get():
        # check for closing window 
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
    if pong_ball.rect.left == WIDTH - 12.5:
        score = score + 1
    if pong_ball.rect.right == 12.5:
        score2 = score2 + 1
        # update 
    all_sprites.update()
    pong_ball_group.update()
    # check to see if pong ball hit one of the pads 
    hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(pong_ball, all_sprites, False, False)
    for hit in hits:
        pong_ball.bounce()
        # draw and render 
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
pong_ball_group.draw(screen)
draw_text(screen, str(score), 50, WIDTH / 2 - 30, 10)
draw_text(screen, str(score2), 50, WIDTH / 2 + 30, 10)
draw_text(screen, "-", 50, WIDTH / 2, 10)
# *after* drawing everything, flip the display 
pg.display.flip()
pg.quit()
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not a debugging service, have you narrowed down the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how you check that the ball has left the screen. Your current check condition will never trigger as `pong_ball.rect.left` will never be equal to `WIDTH - 12.5` as it is an integer.

A simple debugging method is just printing the values you're checking, so adding

```
print(pong_ball.rect.left, WIDTH - 12.5)
```

Will output:

```
1264 1267.5
1267 1267.5
1270 1267.5
1273 1267.5
1276 1267.5
1279 1267.5
625 1267.5
628 1267.5
```

As the ball moves towards the right side of the screen and its position is then reset.

So you see the ball position moves past your limit without triggering your condition.

If you change the comparison to `>` and `<` respectively, the score will update.

However this will cause another problem, which might also be apparent from the debug prints above. There are four frames where the scoring condition is true because the reset position check in `PongBall.update()` does not have a 12.5 pixel leeway. Is this why the leeway exists in the first place? Your future self might appreciate a comment.

But if you change the comparison to remove your 12.5 pixel buffer, then the score doesn't update. This is because the `pong_ball` position is updated *and* reset in its `update()` method.

If we follow your approach for bouncing, we could add a separate `reset` method to `PongBall` and call that when we meet the criteria for scoring.

So your `PongBall` class is now:

```
class PongBall(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.Surface((30, 30))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speedx = random.choice(pong_ball_x)
        self.speedy = random.choice(pong_ball_y)
        self.reset()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top <= 0:
            self.speedy = -self.speedy
        if self.rect.bottom >= HEIGHT:
            self.speedy = -self.speedy

    def reset(self):
        self.rect.x = WIDTH / 2 - 15
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2 - 15

    def bounce(self):
        self.speedx = -self.speedx
```

Your main loop changes to also perform the reset:

```
while running:
    # process input (events)
    for event in pg.event.get():
        # check for closing window
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
    # check for score
    if pong_ball.rect.left > WIDTH - 12.5:
        score = score + 1
        pong_ball.reset()
    if pong_ball.rect.right < 12.5:
        score2 = score2 + 1
        pong_ball.reset()
    # update
    ....
```

Then your score should be behaving correctly.

Comment: Making comments for your "Future Self" - absolutely good advice!  (nice answer too)